# Sprite images not showing with li

Tags: html, css, sprite

Thanks for any advice and suggestions

Not sure why I cannot get the sprite images working using li

When I do not use sprite, I can get the image to show. This is with class gem

Class dice_3, dice_2 and dice_4 does not show

Here is the html

```
<Tip class="tip">
   <article>
    <h1> Chamber</h1><hr>
    <ul>
    <li>
       <h3>  Enter  : </h3> 
       <div clsss="icon dice_3"></div>
       <div clsss="icon dice_4"></div>
    </li> 
    <li>
       <h3> Activate 1  </h3> 
       <div class="icon gem"></div> 
       <h3> : </h3> 
       <div clsss="icon dice_2"></div>
       <div clsss="icon dice_4"></div>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Here is the html

```
.dice_2 {
    width: 25px; height: 25px;
    background: url('img/dice_icon.png') -25px -0;
}


.dice_3 {
    width: 25px; height: 25px;
    background: url('img/dice_icon.png') -50px -0;
}


.dice_4 {
    width: 25px; height: 25px;
    background: url('img/dice_icon.png') -75px -0;
}



.icon {
    transform: scale(0.50);
}
.gem {
    width: 21px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url('img/gem21x30.png');
}
```

`

I have tried using larger images and redoing the sprite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to give `width` , `height` and `background-image` for every icon. Just add these properties in the common class `icon`
Here is an example of image sprite.

```css
.icon{
  background-image: url(https://ik.imagekit.io/tlqsygotu/group_MdNqRpdKP.png);
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-size: auto;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px
}
.icon1{
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.icon2{
  background-position: 0 70px;
}
.icon3{
  background-position: 140px 0;
}
.icon4{
  background-position: 210px 0;
}
.icon5{
  background-position: 280px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon icon1"></div>
<div class="icon icon2"></div>
<div class="icon icon3"></div>
<div class="icon icon4"></div>
<div class="icon icon5"></div>
```